Custom Hilt component
I am currently trying to implement a custom Hilt component by following the guidelines from the article “Using Hilt Custom Component.” Below is the code I’ve written:
@Scope
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class UserScope


@UserScope
@DefineComponent(parent = SingletonComponent::class)
interface UserComponent {
    @DefineComponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): UserComponent
    }
}

@Singleton
class UserComponentManager @Inject constructor(
    private val userAuthSession: UserAuthSession,
    private val userComponentProvider: Provider<UserComponent.Builder>
): GeneratedComponentManager<UserComponent> { /*...*/ }

@ViewModelScoped
class TranscribeTaskRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val dbFactory: DBFactory,
    private val transcribeAgent: TranscribeAgent,
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val bizEncryptService: BizEncryptService
) { /*...*/ }


But I got this error：
The error indicates that Hilt/Dagger is unable to provide an instance of UserComponent.Builder. Specifically, Dagger cannot find a way to provide dagger.internal.Provider<UserComponent.Builder> because there is no @Provides-annotated method for it.
xxx/yyy/EnterApplication_HiltComponents.java:208: 错误: [Dagger/MissingBinding] dagger.internal.Provider<com.xxx.www.base_hilt.UserComponent.Builder> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements EnterApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      dagger.internal.Provider<com.xxx.www.base_hilt.UserComponent.Builder> is injected at
          [xxx.yyy.EnterApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC] com.xxx.www.base_hilt.UserComponentManager(…, userComponentProvider)
      com.xxx.www.base_hilt.UserComponentManager is injected at
          [xxx.yyy.EnterApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC] ...

Is there something that I missed?
